# Openproject 12.4.x - Boards feature is not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angular, openproject

I am using openproject 12.4.x and facing an issue in Boards page. I am unable to create a board. In console, I saw an error like,

```
Transition Rejection($id: 1 type: 2, message: The transition has been superseded by a different transition, detail: Transition#2( ''{} -> 'boards.list'{"flash_message":"null","projects":"projects","projectPath":"92841ba0-ad7d-403f-97b3-6c7050efc576","query_props":"undefined"} )) _
```

On what condition Boards creation will work and why I am getting this error?

In localhost I didn't face this issue but in another environment getting this issue and onClick of a Create button will not respond properly.